# improving the following try and expect

Tags: python, selenium

I have the function below but it is very messy. Any advice on improving the code below?

```
     try:
        driver.find_element_by_id("edit").click()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        self.text.find_element_by_xpath('/..//..//..//td/input[@type="checkbox"]')
        self.text.find_element_by_xpath('/..//..//..//td/input[@value=%s]' % enterValue).click()

    except:
        try:
            self.text.find_element_by_xpath('./..//..//./td/select')
            Select(self.text.find_element_by_xpath('./..//..//./td/select')).select_by_visible_text(enterValue)
        except:
            try:
                self.text.find_element_by_xpath('/..//..//..//td/input[@type="text"]')
                self.text.find_element_by_xpath('/..//..//..//td/input[@type="text"]').sendkeys(enterValue)
            except:
                #do this
```

Comment: See [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) ... SO is for code that's not working. CR will help you improve the working code you already have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Catching specific exceptions instead of everything would be an improvement, but I guess that's not what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper method for the `find_` methods you use that does the try/except within it